# Android RIL command designation

Tags: android, ril

Im learning about RIL (Radio Interface Layer) and baseband commands, and I saw that there is command that it unused by android source:

```
 RIL_REQUEST_ENTER_NETWORK_DEPERSONALIZATION
```

I wonder what its designation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests that network personlization be deactivated

```
"data" is const char ** 
((const char **)(data))[0]] is network depersonlization code

"response" is int *
((int *)response)[0] is the number of retries remaining, or -1 if unknown
```

Valid errors:

```
SUCCESS
RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE (radio resetting)
GENERIC_FAILURE
PASSWORD_INCORRECT
```

Source: ril.h (Android Open Source Project)

Answer (score 1):

Network personalization allows the network operator to personalize a ME so that it can only be used with that particular network operator's SIMs while de-personalization is the process of deactivating the personalization so that the ME ceases to carry out the verification checks.

Besides, Alex has provided details of the API from ril.h.